# PHP Changing index of variable

Tags: php, variables, indexing

$string[$k] = $function[$k]

defined within a foreach loop with index $k. I want $string to be defined as

```
$string[$k] = $function[$(k-5)]
```

except that isn't correct. So for $k=8 I would have

```
$string[8] = $function[3]
```

How do I achieve this?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Your version:

```
$string[$k] = $function[$(k-5)]
```

Correct version:

```
$string[$k] = $function[$k-5]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$string[$k] = $function[$k-5];
```

(Andrew Hare had already suggested that. But he deleted that for some reason.)

Answer (score 0):

Question:  Is $function an array[]  or a function() call?

If $function is an array, you must not access $function[k-5] where k<5;

your for loop should read:

```
for ($k=5; $k<$limit; ++k)
    $string[$k] = $function[$k-5];
```